# Show validation message for formControlName in Angular

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7

I have the following Angular SignUp form:

```
<form [formGroup]="signUp" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <input id="email" type="text" formControlName="email" placeholder="Email">
  <input id="email" type="password" formControlName="password" placeholder="Password">
  <button type="submit" [disabled]="!enquiry.valid">Sign Up</button>
</form>
```

On my component code I am submitting the values to an API.

Is something is wrong the API returns a list of errors which I push to my form errors.

How can I display, for each input, its error message?

I do not need to set any message as the API already returns the correct message.

Comment: Do you want to show the messages next to the components or all in the same place (ex. a summary panel) ?

Comment: I need to show the error message after each input for that input.

Comment: Can you show an example of API response with error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this on a per-input basis, as suggested, you'll need your API to return the errors with the corresponding `FormControl` name, e.g;

```
[
   { name: 'email', errorMessage: 'Email already exists' },
   { name: 'password', errorMessage: 'Password is not strong enough' }
]
```

Once you have that returned, you can iterate the error array and apply to each form controls with `setErrors()`, eg

```
for (let error in errorResponse) {
    this.signUp.get(error.name).setErrors({ error: error.errorMessage });
}
```

At that point, you just need to show the error message for each input.

```
<p *ngIf="signUp.get('email').error">{{signUp.get('email')?.errors?.error}}</p>
```

Stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pqhdul

Comment: I dont think this is a good solution as it searches over the errormessage array every time the validity is checked - searching for the errormessage corresponding to the key. Keyed object access would be saving performance like errors["email"] I think?

Comment: @MartinEckleben - Maybe, the reason I went for this was because the OP mentioned a list of errors, not a keyed object. It also only iterates the array once, when the API returns, NOT when validity is checked by Angular - at that point, the errors are already set, and Angular retrieves them from FormGroups errors object. Even if we used a keyed object, in order to have the FormGroup manage the errors like I have, we'd still need to iterate the object keys to set the appropriate FormControl error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use validation errors for reactive forms (https://angular.io/guide/form-validation).  I think you can set up a custom form validator function (https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validators).  Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

The markup could look something like

```
<form [formGroup]="signUp" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <input id="email" type="text" formControlName="email" placeholder="Email">
  <span id="emailError" *ngIf="apiErrors.emailError">{{apiErrors.emailError}}</span>
  <input id="email" type="password" formControlName="password" placeholder="Password">
  <span id="pwdError" *ngIf="apiErrors.pwdError">{{apiErrors.pwdError}}</span>
  <button type="submit" [disabled]="!enquiry.valid">Sign Up</button>
</form>
```

After format the API response in order to return the needed JSON and then store it in a public property.

Comment: Doing it this way, will show the errors, yes, **but**, it won't make the form invalid, as you're not applying them to the `FormGroup`. Therefore, a form with api errors, will still be read as valid, even when it's not.

Comment: Since you know that there are errors you can set the form as invalid...

Comment: Yes, you can, but that defeats the purpose of reactive forms. There's no point manually setting the form as invalid, if you can have Angular work for you. Additionally, using my suggested answer, you get per-input validity out of the box.

Comment: Why abuse a mechnism, if you can also just use it?